# How to know the version of javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I use javafx to do my project in NetBeans 7.4 IDE. I heard javafx has many versions like 1, 2, 2.1, 8 etc. How can I know the version of javafx I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have latest update of JDK 7 installed, then you are using JavaFX 2.2 and if you have JDK 8, then you automatically are using JavaFX 8.

In order to print the version of JavaFX in your JavaFX program, you can get its system property like following:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperties().get("javafx.runtime.version"));
```